# How to add a button or textView inside a Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I see lot of questions, but the flow what I was looking was not achieved. Basically, I have a simple Activity Class, inside which I am attaching a Fragment.
Now, if I try to addView as in below code snippet

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            hello = SimpleFragment.newInstance("hello","helloo");
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main, hello, "Fragment");
            ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment).getView());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

vg is returning null, because, inside the fragment class, the onCreateView() is not yet reached. 
So My question is how do I know from Activity if fragment view is ready and when I should addViews to the fragment

Comment: terrible idea(accessing UI elements from fragment in activity) ... question is why you need it at all ...

Comment: @Selvin - I didn't get your definition for terribleness in my approach. If any such, please try to explain and guide me to correct approach. All I am trying is figure out a way to Add View elements like button, textview, etc to a fragment dynamically, because I have a scenario where fragment need to be updated with such view elements run-time depending on the data I get from http or socket.

Comment: first you should rather add method to `SimpleFragment` like `addMeNiceButtonWithSomeData(Data data)` fragment should eventually postpone adding UI element to "better time"(like after onCreateView) ... next .... if you need to add this UI element few time you should consider to use ListView .... also listening and sending something over socket countiniously should be rather done in Service ...

Comment: @Selvin comment rather looks like repeating my question bottom-up. :) what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved similar things in the past using ViewTreeeObservers.  I was seeing the same issue as you with null view references.  This was for programmatically adding new child views to a parent view, rather than working with fragment groups, but the same principle *may* work for you.

```
    if (actionButtionPanel.getHeight() == 0) {
        ViewTreeObserver actionButtonPanelObserver = actionButtionPanel.getViewTreeObserver();
        actionButtonPanelObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = getView().findViewById(R.id.llExamDetailInteractionBar).getViewTreeObserver();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
                addActionButtons();
            }
        });
    } else {
        addActionButtons();
    }
```

This checks for the panel (the parent view) not yet being laid out and so it has 0 height, it then registers an observer which is triggered when the view is laid out and calls my function to add child views.

You can see this source in context here: https://github.com/o0rebelious0o/IC2014_ExICS_Android_App/blob/master/ExICS/src/main/java/rce10/ic/ac/uk/exics/Fragments/ExamDetailFragment.java

Comment: from source code, I feel you are trying to achieve same what I was looking for. May be the approach I was looking is not possible, If I am correct. In simple terms - Android doesn't treat a fragment as view, so you can't really treat fragment as view and I might have to think in a different approach rather to achieve adding view dynamically to a fragment.